# Lisp, iterating backwards

Tags: iteration, lisp, common-lisp

Is there a way (with loop or iterate, doesn't matter) to iterate over sequence backwards?

Apart from `(loop for i downfrom 10 to 1 by 1 do (print i))` which works with indexes, and requires length, or `(loop for elt in (reverse seq))` which requires reversing sequence (even worse then the first option).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Iterate can do it](https://common-lisp.net/project/iterate/doc/Sequence-Iteration.html#Sequence-Iteration):

```
(iterate (for x :in-sequence #(1 2 3) :downto 0)
         (princ x))
; => 321
```

As others have noted, this will be **very** inefficient if used on lists.

Answer (score 5):

For lists the easiest is `(dolist (x (reverse list)) ..)` or using the more efficient `nreverse` if the list can be modified.

For vectors an alternative is `dotimes` with index calculation, something like:

```
(let* ((vec #(1 2 3))
       (len (length vec)))
   (dotimes (i len)
      (print (aref vec (- len i 1)))))
```

Typically lists are iterated over from the start as each cons points to the next. Doing it from the back is inherently inefficient.

If you nevertheless have a list and wish fast reverse or random access, an option is to coerce it to a vector using e.g `(coerce my-list 'array)` and then access the elements using `aref` (or coerce to `simple-vector` and use `svref`).

If you are the one building the list, consider creating an adjustable vector with fill-pointer (see `make-array` documentation) and then use `vector-push-extend` to add items. That gives fast random access from the beginning.

Comment: Is there no way to, say, add a clause to iter, smth like `backwards`, which will literally iterate backwards? Is there even a way in lisp to do that?

Comment: Lisp lists are linked in one direction, they're not doubly linked lists. See http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/they-called-it-lisp-for-a-reason-list-processing.html for an example of how lists in lips work. This means that you can only iterate in one direction on basic lists. You could create your own list that is doubly linked such as this one -> https://github.com/krzysz00/dlist

Comment: @AndrewS. How would you write a function that iterates a list backward?

Comment: Wait, i never said list, I mentioned sequences specifically. For list, sure, reverse. But for vector? Simple-array?